# Launch Chrome with extensions disabled, using mouse and menus only, without typing any "commands" or "codes"?

Tags: google-chrome

Note: the scare quotes around "commands" and "codes" do not represent *my* fear of "computer stuff", but that of the person whom I need to remotely *instruct* how to launch Google Chrome without extensions.

Is there a completely non-technical-user-friendly GUI way to accomplish this, one that doesn't require typing any "scary codes" like `\` or `--`, and preferably no typing whatsoever?

EDIT: Incognito mode is a no-go. The specific scenario involves debugging the person's issues with logging-in in a service, and they have a "good" password saved in their regular profile. Those will not be available in incognito mode. Teaching that user how to access saved passwords in their default profile, copy them out and use them in incognito mode is another epic I want to avoid.

EDIT 2: It turns out that incognito mode has access to saved passwords. This makes it a good solution. I am accepting the answer that proposed it.

Comment: If you really want to avoid typing/pasting `--` switches, etc. for some reason, although this is IMO XY problem, then just tell them to go to extensions page and disable all extensions one by one, temporarily.

Comment: No good. The person has saved passwords in their regular profile that won't be available in the incognito mode, and teaching them how to access saved passwords, copy them out and use them in the incognito mode is another epic that I want to avoid. Will edit the question.

Comment: I don't think you replied in the correct place. I proposed just disabling the extensions, does that work and if not then why? What's the goal here in general?

Comment: I have indeed replied in the wrong place. And yes, it is an XY problem. The Y problem is not realistically solvable, but can be circumvented by solving the X problem, therefore the X problem is the focus of the question.

Comment: Why does that elderly person need extensions disabled? If you provide more details, a better solution may appear.

Comment: In order to rule out the possibility that an issue the person is experiencing is caused by an extension. Stop trying to XYfy this, ok? It is **NOT** an XY problem if the solution to Y can only be useful once, but a solution to X will be useful in many similar scenarios. "I want to learn to fish". "Why?" "Because I am hungry right now". "This is an XY problem. Here, take this fish".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions are disabled when Chrome is in Incognito mode.

All you need to communicate to the person is :

Click the three-points vertical sign on top-right of the Chrome window
and then click on "New Incognito window".

Comment: No good. The person has saved passwords in their regular profile that won't be available in the incognito mode, and teaching them how to access saved passwords, copy them out and use them in the incognito mode is another epic that I want to avoid. Will edit the question.

Comment: Just tested it : The passwords in Incognito mode are filled in from Chrome's password manager. Incognito only means that after the session ends Chrome destroys all created cookies and doesn't record any websites that you visited and disables any extension not marked as available in this mode.

Comment: OK now that changes things.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible to do without typing anything. You will require a mouse and how to use it to copy/paste however.

1 - First, you’ll need to create a desktop shortcut for the Chrome application. The following instructions are the same for Windows 10 and Windows 11. To get started, right-click an empty spot on your desktop and select New > Shortcut.

[image]

2 - In the “Create Shortcut” dialog, click “Browse.” When the “Browse for Files or Folders” window opens, navigate to the location where you’ve installed Google Chrome by clicking the arrows beside each sub-folder as you open them.

Chrome is usually installed under C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application. (If it’s not in “Program Files,” also try “Program Files (x86)” on your C: drive.) When you see chrome.exe, select it and click “OK.”

[image]

3 - Back in the “Create Shortcut” window, locate the text input box labeled “Type the location of the item,” which should already be filled with a path similar to "**C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe**" .

Click the text input box just after the last quotation mark to place a blinking cursor there:
[image]

4 - Using your mouse, select and copy the following text to clipboard:

```
--disable-extensions
```

5 - In that text box, press space once, then simply paste it with your mouse. (Yes, there are `- -` but don't worry, you can use your mouse to copy and paste, no typing as you requested)

6 - When you’re finished, the entire contents of the text box should look similar to the following, although your exact path may be different):

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-extensions
```

7 - Click “Next” to continue.
[image]

8 - On the next page, use the text box to name the shortcut “Chrome (Extensions Disabled)” or something memorable that will remind you this is a special shortcut. Then click “Finish.”
[image]

All of this is possible without using a keyboard, simply by using a mouse.

[Source](https://www.howtogeek.com/779557/how-to-start-google-chrome-without-extensions-on-windows/)

Comment: Please, whenever you write "you will need" in your answer, think "elderly computerophobic person will need". I don't need a procedure that I will be able to perform myself. I need a procedure that I will be able to describe to a computerophobic person without scaring them to death. There's no way that person will be willing to manually create a desktop shortcut and retype anything that contains a `--` in a scary input box in a complicated dialog hidden in "THE SYSTEM".

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski The steps are simple, and I've answered your question on how to do this without typing. My solution does not contain anything that requires typing. Copy Paste, that's it. If the person is 'computerphobic', there isn't much I can do about that.

Comment: The question asks for a non-technical-user-friendly way. I am a "technical user", but I use Linux on a daily basis and haven't done anything nontrivial in Windows for ages, and your recipe for creating a desktop shortcut in Windows even scares _me_ a little bit.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski  Computer science can be scary (like anything), if we don't take the time to learn how it works. What I've posted isn't very technical and only requires a few steps, but is no more complicated than baking a cake.